# Python converting from c# Calculating CRC8 from 4/5 bytes frame

Tags: c#, python, c, crc

I've got a frame build like this : **{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}**.

C# script to calculate **crc8**

```
   u8 Crc(u8 *buffer, u8 length) 
   {
        u8 crc = 0, idx;
        while ( length-- != 0 ) 
        {
            crc = crc ^ *buffer++;
            for ( idx = 0; idx < 8; ++idx ) 
            {
                if ( crc & 0x01 ) crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8C;
                else crc >>= 1;
            }
       }
       return crc;
    }
```

can someone show me how to write it correctly in Python?

Comment: That Tkinter stuff is irrelevant to the CRC calculation.

Comment: Where did you get this crc8 algorithm?  The bitshift directions and polynomial seem odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site you linked appears to use the same algorithm as what you've posted. It's easy enough to translate to Python, all of the bit twiddling code remains the same, all you need to change is the code that loops over the input buffer.

```
def crc8(buff):
    crc = 0
    for b in buff:
        crc ^= b
        for i in range(8):
            if crc & 1:
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ 0x8C
            else:
                crc >>= 1
    return crc

buff = [0x12, 0xAB, 0x34]
crc = crc8(buff)
print(hex(crc))
```

**output**

```
0x17
```

This code also works correctly if `buff` is a `bytes` or `bytearray` object.